# Assigning a specific value in sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an sql like this:

```
 SELECT temp.inst_id,
       ' ',
       gv.instance_name,
       gv.host_name,
       CASE WHEN component IS NULL THEN 'others' ELSE component END
          component,
       ROUND (SUM (used_mb), 1) used_mb
  FROM (SELECT inst_id,
               CASE
                  WHEN name = 'buffer_cache' THEN 'db_buffer_cache'
                  WHEN name = 'log_buffer' THEN 'log_buffer'
                  ELSE pool
               END
                  component,
               CASE
                  WHEN name = 'buffer_cache'
                  THEN
                     (  (  (  bytes
                            -   (SELECT COUNT (*)
                                   FROM gv$bh
                                  WHERE     inst_id = x.inst_id
                                        AND status = 'free')
                              * (SELECT t.VALUE
                                   FROM gv$parameter t
                                  WHERE     t.inst_id = x.inst_id
                                        AND t.name = 'db_block_size'))
                         / 1024)
                      / 1024)
                  WHEN name != 'free memory'
                  THEN
                     ( (bytes / 1024) / 1024)
               END
                  used_mb
          FROM gv$sgastat x) temp,
       gv$instance gv
 WHERE gv.inst_id = temp.inst_id
GROUP BY component,
       temp.inst_id,
       gv.instance_name,
       gv.host_name
```

Here is the output of this query:

```
1   irisdb1 db_buffer_cache     27,6    27,5
1   irisdb1 java pool            0,2    
1   irisdb1 large pool           0,2     0,1
1   irisdb1 log_buffer           0,2     0,2
1   irisdb1 shared pool          3,7       3
1   irisdb1 others                 0       0
2   irisdb2 db_buffer_cache     27,6    27,4
2   irisdb2 java pool            0,1    
2   irisdb2 large pool           0,4     0,2
2   irisdb2 log_buffer           0,2     0,2
2   irisdb2 shared pool            4     3,4
2   irisdb2 others                 0       0
```

As you can see in the output, some rows(2nd and 8th lines) has empty value in the last column. What i want is to assign `0`(double value) to that empty values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the value is `NULL`, then you can use `coalesce()` (or several other functions)` to put in a value:

```
 SELECT temp.inst_id,
       ' ',
       gv.instance_name,
       gv.host_name,
       CASE WHEN component IS NULL THEN 'others' ELSE component END
          component,
       COALESE( ROUND (SUM (used_mb), 1), 0.0) used_mb
```

Comment: One of the functions are NVL, i can use it like NVL(used_mb,0). Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to give it a default value if it is `NULL`:

```
COALESCE(ROUND (SUM (used_mb), 1),0.0) used_mb
```

Comment: T-SQL supports ISNULL, but Oracle falls back on COALESCE *(afaik)*.

Comment: @MatBailie Whoops, ignored the Oracle tag, changing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `ELSE` clause to the `CASE` statement for `used_mb`

```
           CASE
              WHEN name = 'buffer_cache'
              THEN
                 (  (  (  bytes
                        -   (SELECT COUNT (*)
                               FROM gv$bh
                              WHERE     inst_id = x.inst_id
                                    AND status = 'free')
                          * (SELECT t.VALUE
                               FROM gv$parameter t
                              WHERE     t.inst_id = x.inst_id
                                    AND t.name = 'db_block_size'))
                     / 1024)
                  / 1024)
              WHEN name != 'free memory'
              THEN
                 ( (bytes / 1024) / 1024)
              ELSE 0
           END
              used_mb
```